# What's the limitation of LTF on mobile?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4, tlf

As we are targeting mobile in our Flex Mobile based project, we are using adobe text layout engine, ( TLF )

We've noticed that when typing in RTL language ( Arabic ) the cursor is at the beginning of text field, when text addition is at end of field ..

Any one had such behavior? 
We've noticed that this problem occurs only at mobile target.

What would be an alternative in-case this is a know limitation in Adobe TLF?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you set the TextLayoutFormat direction to RTL? you did not mention that in your question.

Comment: Yes , just change the direction of text to right but the cursor still in beginning of text

Comment: TLF stands for "try, laugh, fail." It's full of little quirks like this that need to be bridged!

Comment: Do not use TLF, it is deprecated. Write your own function that handles it, it is rather easy.

Comment: @Fygo I think Flex itself is deprecated :)

Comment: @Amer so, what's your choice when you build cross platform app?

Comment: @SameerH.Ibra I am not mobile developer, but from what i always hear everywhere, you have two choices depends on your favorite language: `kendoui.com/mobile.aspx` if you are good in HTML5/JavaScript, and `xamarin.com` if you prefer C# like me.

Comment: @Amer - FYI, xamarin.com is using Flash to play their videos, and they have javascript errors on the page. A little unfair since it looks like a solid offering, but still ;) Secondly, AIR is a fantastic framework. HTML5 is cute on paper but I find AIR/Starling to be much more predictable and dependable at the moment. I think the problem with most Flash dev's is they are still stuck in classic flash thinking, and need to switch to using the gpu for mobile/cross-platform. Non-gpu vector stuff is slow in any framework (often faster in flash), gpu bitmaps are fast in all of them- and Flash is fun.

Comment: @davidkomer I agree that for a game developer, Flash/AIR with something great like Starling is far better compared with HTML5. But i don't think the same thing goes for Apps, you cannot trust Adobe as a tool vendor for application developers anymore, especially after it has stated publically in their famous [dark/damn] roadmap that they shift Flash focus to be a gaming tool only, and gave their advice to other flash app devs to switch their apps to HTML5/Native apps, etc. I think (from a developer perspective) that Adobe is not trustworthy anymore.

Comment: to sum, I think (for me at least) anyone still think of Flash as it was before should rethink again, not because flash cannot do it, but because Adobe do not want that to be.

Comment: agreed- it now depends much more on the type of app... though I'd still say that if the app does not depend on heavy graphics manipulation, you can use the old vector-based stuff and it works beautifully across platforms. The only area where it sucks, honestly, is text and edge cases that need a mix of stagevideo/regular video/stage3d/vector. Though text is a definitely a big issue and apps that need to use it as their core should definitely check into other solutions- agreed 100%

Answer (score 0):

For Mobile text *input* you should ignore it altogether and use StageText as it will operate correctly using native device. Also allows mixing bilingual text etc. though it does not work with embedded fonts.

For output/rendering, TLFTextField works perfectly and can then be drawn to a Stage3D graphic, for example (on Mobile you are most likely wanting to use GPU graphics via something like Starling.)

So a workflow which some follow (myself, but maybe more importantly, Feathers), is to actually separate the two. When the user needs to edit, hide the TLFTextField and show a StageText pre-populated with the string. It will always be on top-most layer. When the user is done editing, hide the StageText and show the TLFTextField (or blit it to an Image) in the correct layer.

Comment: Our problem in the editing of the text, and the StageText has the same problem: the cursor remain at the beginning when we writre arabic inside it (note that StageText don't have direction property)

Comment: on the instance of StageText, try setting .locale = "ara"